# Inequality involving summation

Tags: inequality

Can someone help me with this inequality:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt i}}\leq \dfrac{2n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Thank you.

Comment: Comment:  $\frac{2n}{\sqrt{n}}=2\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes. but I think it makes little difference in proving the inequality.

Comment: Can someone demonstrate a non-mathematical induction way?

Comment: Technically, it is not possible to prove anything about $\sum_{i=1}^n$ without either explicitly or implicitly using induction. You are just asking for an answer that hides the induction.

Comment: As to whether simplifying $\frac{2n}{\sqrt{n}}=2\sqrt{n}$ is useful: It obviously isn't technically useful, but it is useful from a human reasoning point of view, because a human brain will more easily see that $f(x)=2\sqrt{x}$ is the integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ 2\left(\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i-1}\right) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{i}+\sqrt{i-1}}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\tag{1} $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\leq 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{i}-\sqrt{i-1}\right)=2\sqrt{n}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: A very nice solution. Thank you.:)

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^{-1/2}$ is decreasing in $x$,

$i^{-1/2}\leq\int_{i-1}^ix^{-1/2}dx$

Adding up,

$\sum_{i=1}^ni^{-1/2}\leq\int_0^nx^{-1/2}dx=2n^{1/2}$